# Does anyone know of a comprehensive listing of geostationary weather satellites?

Tags: weather-satellites, open-data

Periods of operation at longitude--current as well as historical. The [historical list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_satellites_in_geosynchronous_orbit) is incomplete. Is there a single site with status of **operational** satellites (real-time) or do you have to go to every operator you can think of?

Comment: Is this question on topic?

Comment: @Siv See meta question [Are questions about the availability of information on topic?](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/120/are-questions-about-the-availability-of-information-on-topic)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [WMO OSCAR](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/satellites) database is a list of *all* Earth observation satellites¹.  The resulting table can be sorted by orbit type, status (inactive/operation/planned), agency, and other aspects.  From their own description:

> This table shows all known past, current and future satellites for meteorological and earth observation purposes.It can be sorted by clicking on the column headers. The filter on the right allows to display only specific satellites.

A screenshot showing three GOES satellites and the scroll-bar on the right is shown below:

[image: OSCAR SATS screenshot]

Note that OSCAR has a lot more capabilities than this.  For anything Earth-observation-from-space related, it is a superb resource.

---

¹Except classified (spy) satellites...

Comment: That's (almost) perfect. I checked the one satellite I definitely know moved--GOES-7. The history of locations is on a details page. Better than nothing, but a (small) pain to have to look at every one of them. NB: The table makes a distinction between geostationary (GEO) and geosynchronous (GeoSync) orbits, which is really great; they are different. Thank you!

Comment: +1 **Except classified (spy) satellites**

Comment: @blunders Unlikely for those to be geostationary…

Answer (score 3):

I queried Wikidata for "instance of" = "weather satellite" and came up with this list:

[http://tools.wmflabs.org/wikidata-todo/autolist.html?q=CLAIM[31%3A209363%2C0%3A%28%29]](http://tools.wmflabs.org/wikidata-todo/autolist.html?q=CLAIM%5b31%3A209363%2C0%3A%28%29%5d)

Please remember that Wikidata still needs a huge amount of work, before queries can be judged accurate and complete (The project just started 2 years ago). If you need help improving the listing I can help you out, because I am heavily involved in Wikidata (Or coordinate your effort with the Space WikiProject: [https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:WikiProject_Space](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata%3aWikiProject_Space)). More complex queries will be possible in the future when data density increases (the query is missing the "operational status" you would like to query).

Comment: That's pretty cool. I wish it worked. By the way, not all weather satellites are geostationary. And, contrary to the name, some geostationary satellites are moved, thus the need for time at longitude information.

Comment: @kwknowles Information about the orbit could be stored at Wikidata. But filling a database that contains all of the worlds information takes some time.